# How to change the "Terms of Use" and "Privacy Statement" in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

How we can change text and wording of "Terms of Use" and "Privacy Statement" pages in Dot Net Nuke from admin?

Answer (score 4):

Those texts are part of the resources files.

Go to menu "Admin > Languages" and click for edit its content for the site or the host.
Keep on the edition of the "GlobalResources" file.
Search for "MESSAGE_PORTAL_PRIVACY.Text" and "MESSAGE_PORTAL_TERMS.Text" and modify them.

If you modify the system version, a future upgrade of your DNN installation could overwrite your customization.
Host mode will impact all websites on the instance.
Site mode will impact only the current website.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it might still help someone:

Tested with DNN 08.00.04 there are different methods to get a custom terms page without editing the language files (which feels a bit cumbersome)

To have your own /terms page you just create named "terms" in the navigation root.
DNN will show up your newly created page if you browse yoursite.com/terms

You can also redirect to another page from there (create a "link" page instead of "content" page, this in case you want to call your page AGB and have this in the url (yoursite.com/agb)

If you have https://dnnurlmanagement.codeplex.com/ installed you can simplifiy the steps above with just adding a "custom page URL" 301 redirect rule with "/terms" to any page you want to show up as /terms.

Answer (score 0):

Go to site admin section here Admin -> Language -> edit host -> find your required field "Terms of use" and "Privacy". you can change here or edit it.